# yom-tov and chagim-holidays tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

- The [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov) tag wiki excerpt: "The Hebrew phrase for "holiday". Used for religious holidays such as Rosh Hashana, Purim, etc..."
- The [chagim-holidays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chagim-holidays) tag wiki excerpt: "the three pilgrimage festivals: Sukkot, Pesach, Shavu'ot."

That distinction sounds good to me. So does:

- Use [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov) for questions about holidays on which activity is restricted.
- Use [chagim-holidays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chagim-holidays) for any Jewish-holiday question (except those for which a finer tag exists).

So does:

- Merge one of the tags into the other, and make the latter about all Jewish holidays (except those for which a finer tag exists).

The current state of affairs, though, is:

- Use either tag for anything.

Please state and upvote/downvote your preference among these and any others ideas you may think of.

(Don't bother upvoting/downvoting this question, as there are several conflicting suggestions in it and no one will know which one you like/dislike.)

---

**Update:** Per the votes, I've accepted [Isaac Moses's answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/804). I've edited the tag wikis and excerpts and retagged existing questions accordingly.

Comment: [tag:chagim] is a synonym of [tag:yom-tov]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the second option. Colloquially (for the most part, in the circles in which I travel) "Yom Tov" refers to holidays on which there's cessation of work, while "chagim" or "holidays" refers to Jewish holidays more generally. This seems like a reasonable way to divide these tags.

"Chag" can have a technical meaning equivalent to how I defined "Yom Tov" above. It can also refer specifically to the three pilgrimage festivals, as in your first option. It can also refer specifically to Sukkot. I think that in a tagging sense, we should pick one meaning, and the colloquial meaning, incorporating the fact that "chag" is the generic modern Hebrew translation of "holiday," seems the right one. Tag wikis and retagging as necessary can be used to make it clear that in a tagging sense here, that's what "chagim" means.

Comment: +1. And drop the [tag:chagim]→[tag:yom-tov] synonym.

Comment: @msh210 Yes! That's just confusing in this context.

Answer (score 0):

New option: use [yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov) for questions about holidays on which activity is restricted, alias [chagim-holidays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chagim-holidays) to it, and *drop* the other usage.  All of the holidays have holiday-specific tags.  When would we want to tag a question "holidays" in general if not to ask about yom-tov restrictions (like the recent cooking question)?  We don't need a general "holidays" bucket.

Comment: Fair enough, but what about http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12624 and similar (questions that have to do with the holidays generally)?

Comment: @msh210 hmm, good question -- I hadn't noticed that one before.  But is it really a question about holidays?  It involves holidays, but it's really about interpretation, right?  The question isn't tagged for wine and milk and ... either.  If this question isn't a singleton then maybe we need an all-holidays tag?  But explicitly -- the *all* there is important, else we'll get mish-mash.